# i want to see all the users in django admin panel and i can select more than one user

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

hello i had done some modification in models and get the User.username and inserted them in a user_list and in multiselectfield(choices=user_list)
is was working fine but in the case as i made/create a new user
and i go to the application to select multiple users, my newly made user is not showing there
until i restart the django server

my model is like that:

```
class Video(models.Model):
listo = []
user = User.objects.all()
for i in user:
    a = (str(i), str(i))
    listo.append(a)
print("this is listo", listo)

caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
video = models.FileField(upload_to="video/%y",null=True,blank=True)
show_to = MultiSelectField(choices=User.username)
# show_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
url_video= models.URLField(blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.caption
```

the thing i want is to instantly show the newly made user in the django application so i could not restart the server again and again.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defined Model choices are set once when your server start or restart, So your choices not updated after adding users.

You create a ModelForm for your model and set choices for model field in ****init**** method of form. When you open form, every time call constructor of your form and set choices.

```
from django import forms

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VideoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['show_to'].choices = self.get_dynamic_choices()

    def get_dynamic_choices(self):
        choices = [(obj.id, obj.username) for obj in User.objects.all()]
        return choices
```